# Attribute that checks strings and adds three digit ellipsis

Tags: c#

Is there an attribute that can check a string and add a three digit ellipsis to the end of a string automatically if the length of the string is greater than max length?

Class Example:

```
public class Test() {
  [AddEllipsis("...", MaxLength=30)]
  String Name { get; set; }
}
```

example:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.Name = "123456789012345678901234567890abc123";
Console.WriteLine(t.Name);

// Might look like "123456789012345678901234567..."
```

Also prefer it to be added dynamically.

Comment: Should that be AOP (aspect oriented programming)? If so, which framework do you have?

Comment: Do you want that done when setting the value or only when getting it?

Comment: Getting it of course if you see his code usage.

Comment: I was thinking like Entity Framework or generic POCO models checking display length.  LIke this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx

Comment: @EmpereurAiman: with `t.Name` he is setting the value. Perhaps the dots are added at that time.

Comment: If you're expecting the property to return the ellipses *regardless of where it's called from*, then no - it's not possible in 'plain C#'. You can only do that with aspects, for which there are a few libraries. If you're doing it to render the string to a form, then you'll need to write your own renderer which reads the attribute.

Comment: I'm using this link now: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom getter for the property

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _name;

    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name => DoEllipsisTransform(_name, 30);

    private static string DoEllipsisTransform(string value, int maxLength)
    {
        return value.Length > maxLength
            ? $"{value.Substring(0, maxLength - 3)}..."
            : value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't really change the model b/c its in a black box.  Anything I add to the model I need to add to it dynamically after the fact.

Comment: Do you mean dynamically as in adding the attribute via reflection?

Comment: Yes.  At run time.  Unfortunately the other method is not possible b/c I'm working on existing code base using Entity Framework Data First model.  The models get constantly recreated and all updates need to be updated dynamically or at run time.

Comment: @RetroCoder: why don't you add such very important information to the question? Being able to change the code or not is a huge limitation we need to know about.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think about it until you ask the question.

Comment: But it is only a preference.  If I have to manually add it each time to make it work that would be a short term solution as long as it works.